# Navigation bar html / css3

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation bar for my website, now how do I make it appear on all the pages? I tried different many ways but not working
I will appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Master pages](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp).
You need to add your navigation bar to a master page, then create all other web pages as content pages. This will automatically make all "child" pages with the master page's controls.